# binding values to frames in the environment model

Tags: scheme, parameter-passing, lisp, sicp, lexical-scope

I am a little confused on how the environment model of evaluation works, and hoping someone could explain.

SICP says:

> The environment model specifies: To apply a procedure to arguments,
>   create a new environment containing a frame that binds the parameters
>   to the values of the arguments. The enclosing environment of this
>   frame is the environment specified by the procedure. Now, within this
>   new environment, evaluate the procedure body.

First example:

If I:

```
(define y 5)
```

in the global environment, then call

```
(f y)
```

where

```
(define (f x) (set! x 1))
```

We construct a new environment (e1). Within e1, x would be bound to the value of y (5). In the body, the value of x would now be 1. I found that y is still 5. I believe the reason for this is because x and y are located in different frames. That is, I completely replaced the value of x. I modified the frame where x is bound, not just its value. Is that correct?

Second example:

If we have in the global environment:

```
(define (cons x y)
  (define (set-x! v) (set! x v))
  (define (set-y! v) (set! y v))
  (define (dispatch m)
    (cond ((eq? m 'car) x)
          ((eq? m 'cdr) y)
          ((eq? m 'set-car!) set-x!)
          ((eq? m 'set-cdr!) set-y!)
          (else (error "Undefined 
                 operation: CONS" m))))
  dispatch)

(define (set-car! z new-value)
  ((z 'set-car!) new-value)
  z)
```

Now I say:

(define z2 (cons 1 2))

Suppose z2 has a value the dispatch procedure in an environment called e2, and I call:

```
(set-car! z2 3)
```

Set-car! creates a new environment e3. Within e3, the parameter z is bound to the value of z2 (the dispatch procedure in e2) just like in my first example. After the body is executed, z2 is now '(3 2). I think set-car! works the way it does is because I am changing the state of the object held by z (which is also referenced by z2 in global), but not replacing it. That is, I did not modify the frame where z is bound.

In this second example it appears that z2 in global and z in e3 are shared. I am not sure about my first example though. Based on the rules for applying procedures in the environment model, it appears x and y are shared although it is completely undetectable because 5 does not have local state.

Is everything I said correct? Did I misunderstood the quote?

Comment: Is the call `(f 5)` or `(f y)`?

Comment: Pretty sure you meant to write (f y) too

Comment: @Renzo (f y). Edited. Thanks.

Comment: @John Clements Edited. Thanks. (f y).

Comment: > * After the body is executed, z2 is now '(3 2)*  After the body is executed, `z2` is still a fake cons cell with a functional interface and not a real cons cell.   A cons pair, by the way, is notated `(1 . 2)` not `(1 2)`; `(1 2)` is two cons cells: `(1 . (2 . ()))`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question: assuming that you meant to write `(f y)` in your first question rather than `(f 5)`, the reason that y is not modified is that racket (like most languages) is a "call by value" language. That is, values are passed to procedure calls. In this case, then the argument `y` is evaluated to `5` before the call to `f` is made. Mutating the `x` binding does not affect the `y` binding.

To answer your second question: in your second example, there are shared environments. That is, `z` is a function that is closed over an environment (you called it `e2`). Each call to `z` creates a new environment that is linked to the existing `e2` environment. Performing mutation on either `x` or `y` in this environment affects all future references to the `e2` environment.

Summary: passing the value of a variable is different from passing a closure that contains that variable. If I say

`(f y)`

... the after the call is done, 'y' will still refer to the same value[*]. If I write

`f (lambda (...) ... y ...)`

(that is, passing a closure that has a reference to `y`, then y might be bound to a different value after the call to `f`.

If you find this confusing, you're not alone. The key is this: don't stop using closures. Instead, stop using mutation.

[*] if `y` is a mutable value, it may be mutated, but it will still be the "same" value. see note above about confusion.

Comment: So in the second example, what does x and y have? A pointer to z?

Comment: x and y are bindings in an environment that's created when `cons` is first called. The z value is a procedure with a link/pointer to that environment.

Comment: I feel that I should add that Scheme is no different from C or Java in its treatment of mutable and immutable values; the only difference here is that closures allow you to store these environments, making them essentially another form of mutable value.

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR:* simple values in Scheme are immutable, are copied in full when passed as arguments into functions. Compound values are mutable, are passed as a copy of a pointer, whereas the copied pointer points to the same memory location as the original pointer does.

---

What you're grappling with is known as "mutation". Simple values like *5* are immutable. There's no "`set-int!`" to change `5` to henceforth hold the value *42* in our program. And it is good that there isn't.

But a variable's value is mutable. A variable is a binding in a function invocation's frame, and it can be changed with `set!`. If we have

```
(define y 5)
(define (foo x) (set! x 42) (display (list x x)))
(foo 5)
   --> foo is entered
       foo invocation environment frame is created as { x : {int 5} }
       x's binding's value is changed: the frame is now { x : {int 42} }
       (42 42)    is displayed
       y still refers to 5 in the global environment
```

But if `foo` receives a value that is itself holding mutable references, which can be mutated, i.e. changed "in place", then though foo's frame itself doesn't change, the value to which a binding in it is referring can be.

```
(define y (cons 5 6))     ; Scheme's standard cons
   --> a cons cell is created in memory, at {memory-address : 123}, as
                   {cons-cell {car : 5} {cdr : 6} } 
(define (foo x) (set-car! x 42) (display (list x x)))
(foo y)
   --> foo is entered
       foo invocation environment frame is created as 
             { x : {cons-cell-reference {memory-address : 123}} }
       x's binding's value is *mutated*: the frame is still
             { x : {cons-cell-reference {memory-address : 123}} }
           but the cons cell at {memory-address : 123} is now
                   {cons-cell {car : 42} {cdr : 6} } 
       ((42 . 6) (42 . 6))    is displayed
       y still refers to the same binding in the global environment
         which still refers to the same memory location, which has now 
         been altered in-place: at {memory-address : 123} is now
                   {cons-cell {car : 42} {cdr : 6} }
```

In Scheme, `cons` is a primitive which creates mutable cons cells which can be altered *in-place* with `set-car!` and `set-cdr!`.

What these SICP exercises intend to show is that it is not necessary to have it as a primitive built-in procedure; that it could be implemented by a user, even if it weren't built-in in Scheme. Having `set!` is enough for that.

---

Another jargon for it is to speak of "boxed" values. If I pass *5* into some function, when that function returns I'm guaranteed to still have my *5*, because it was passed by copying its value, setting the function invocation frame's binding to reference the copy of the value *5* (which is also just an integer *5* of course). This is what is referred to as "pass-by-value".

But if I "box" it and pass `(list 5)` in to some function, the value that is copied -- in *Lisp* -- is a pointer to this "box". This is referred to as "pass-by-pointer-value" or something.

If the function mutates that box with `(set-car! ... 42)`, it is changed in-place and I will henceforth have *42* in that box, `(list 42)` -- under the same memory location as before. My environment frame's binding will be unaltered -- it will still reference the same object in memory -- but the value itself will have been changed, altered in place, mutated.

This works because a box is a compound datum. Whether I put a simple or compound value in it, the box itself  (i.e. the mutable cons cell)  is not simple, so will be passed by pointer value -- only the pointer will be copied, not what it points to.

Comment: What about procedures? Suppose I pass a procedure called g to f like (f g), where g has local state and f intends to change g's state by passing a message to it. Would f's parameter have a pointer to g?

Comment: each value is what it is. in your example from the question, the value created by `(define z (cons 1 2))` is a procedure which carries with it its enclosing environment, where all the `x`, `y`, `dispatch` bindings are located. if you pass that into some function, it still has no access into the internals of `z`, but, it can do with `z` what `z` is designed to, and allows it to do -- i.e., call `(z 'car)` will cause *`z`* to access *its* internals.

Comment: so, yes. you've passed `g` to `f`; it got passes as a copy of the pointer to the memory object which *is* `g`. the parameter of `f`, let's say it is called `param`, cn be used just as `g` can be used. If `f`'s code calls `(param 'message)` it will be as if `(g 'message)` was called.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks. It is unfortunate that SICP does not take the time to mention about copies of values and pointers to procedures, or pointers to compound procedures in general. Aren't these three things too important to ignore?

Comment: I guess they wanted to keep things a bit more abstract, or tentative. Or maybe they wanted a reader to think over all this details themself. SICP just uses "binding" and "set!" as a given.

Answer (score 1):

`x` bound to the value of `y` means that `x` is a new binding which receives a copy of the same value that `y` contains. `x` and `y` are not aliases to a shared memory location.

Though due to issues of optimization, bindings are not exactly memory locations, you can model their behavior that way. That is to say, you can regard an environment to be a bag of storage locations named by symbols.

Educational Scheme-in-Scheme evaluators, in fact, use association lists for representing environments. Thus `(let ((x 1) (y 2)) ...)` creates an environment which simply looks like `((y . 1) (x . 2))`. The storage locations are the `cdr` fields of the `cons` pairs in this list, and their labels are the symbols in the `car` fields. The cell itself is the binding; the symbol and location are bound together by virtue of being in the same `cons` structure.

If there is an outer environment surrounding this `let`, then these association pairs can just be pushed onto it with cons:

```
(let ((z 3))
  ;; env is now ((z . 3))
  (let ((x 1) (y 2))
     ;; env is now ((y . 2) (x . 1) (z . 3))
```

The environment is just a stack of bindings that we push onto. When we capture a lexical closure, we just take the current pointer and stash it into the closure object.

```
(let ((z 3))
  ;; env is now ((z . 3))
  (let ((x 1) (y 2))
     ;; env is now ((y . 2) (x . 1) (z . 3))
     (lambda (a) (+ x y z a))
     ;; lambda is an object with these three pices:
     ;; - the environment ((y . 2) (x . 1) (z . 3))
     ;; - the code (+ x y z a)
     ;; - the parameter list (a)
     )
  ;; after this let is done, the environment is again ((z . 3))
  ;; but the above closure maintains the captured one
)
```

So suppose we call that `lambda` with an argument 10.  The lambda takes the parameter list `(a)` and binds it to the argument list to create a new environment:

```
((a . 1))
```

This new environment is not made in a vacuum; it is created as an extension to the captured environment. So, really:

```
((a . 1) (y . 2) (x . 1) (z . 3))
```

Now, in this effective environment, the body `(+ x y z a)` is executed.

Everything you need to understand about environments can be understood in reference to this cons pair model of bindings.

Assignment to a variable? That's just `set-cdr!` on a cons-based binding.

What is "extending an environment"? It's just pushing a cons-based binding onto the front.

What is "fresh binding" of a variable? That's just the allocation of a new cell with `(cons variable-symbol value)` and extending the environment with it by pushing it on.

What is "shadowing" of a variable? If an environment contains `(... ((a . 2)) ...)` and we push a new binding `(a . 3)` onto this environment, then this `a` is now visible, and `(a . 2)` is hidden, simply because the `assoc` function searches linearly and finds `(a . 2)` first! The inner-to-outer environment lookup is perfectly modeled by `assoc`. Inner bindings appear to the left of outer bindings, closer to the head of the list and are found first.

The semantics of sharing all follow from the semantics of these lists of cells. In the assoc list model, environment sharing occurs when two environment assoc lists share the same tail. For instance, each time we call our lambda above, a new `(a . whatever)` argument environment is created, but it extends the same captured environment tail. If the lambda changes `a`, that is not seen by the other invocations, but if it changes `x`, then the other invocations will see it. `a` is private to the lambda invocation, but `x`, `y` and `z` are external to the lambda, in its captured environment.

If you fall back on this assoc list model mentally, you will not go wrong as far as working out the behavior of environments, including arbitrarily complex situations.

Real implementations basically just optimize around this. for instance, a variable that is initialized from a constant like `42` and never assigned does not have to exist as an actual environment entry at all; the optimization called "constant propagation" can just replace occurrences of that variable with `42`, as if it were a macro. Real implementations may use hash tables or other structures for the environment levels, not assoc lists. Real implementations may be compiled: lexical environments can be compiled according to various strategies such as "closure conversion". Basically, an entire lexical scope can be flattened into a single vector-like object. When a closure is made at run time, the entire vector is duplicated and initialized. Compiled code doesn't refer to variable symbols, but to offsets in the closure vector, which is substantially faster: no linear search through an assoc list is required.

Comment: the book uses basically the same a-list model, it just wraps each environment frame as a separate entity in its own list, and uses a list of frames as an environment.

Comment: if the implementation language were C, e.g., the natural choice there for representing each frame would be an array. So environment would be a linked list of frame arrays.